# WPF Report Printing

Tags: c#, wpf, printing, crystal-reports

I am generating a crystal report using C# and WPF.

My code so far is

```
report.PrintOptions.PaperSize = (CrystalDecisions.Shared.PaperSize)System.Drawing.Printing.PaperKind.A5;
report.PrintToPrinter(2, true, 0, 0);
crystalReportsViewer1.ViewerCore.ReportSource = report;
crystalReportsViewer1.ToggleSidePanel = SAPBusinessObjects.WPF.Viewer.Constants.SidePanelKind.None;
```

I need to show a dialog box ie the PrintDialog to allow user **just** to select the printer he wants to print on and rest of the printing settings are done by me in the code. Please suggest ....

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code

```
        PrintDialog printDialog1 = new PrintDialog();

        if (printDialog1.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            report.PrintOptions.PrinterName = printDialog1.PrintQueue.Name;
            report.PrintOptions.PaperSize = (CrystalDecisions.Shared.PaperSize)System.Drawing.Printing.PaperKind.A5;
            report.PrintToPrinter(2, true, 0, 0);
            crystalReportsViewer1.ViewerCore.ReportSource = report;
            crystalReportsViewer1.ToggleSidePanel = SAPBusinessObjects.WPF.Viewer.Constants.SidePanelKind.None;
        }
```

System.Printing must be in your references so that you can use PrintQueue.Name.